# Algorithm complexity, solving recursive equation

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, complexity-theory, master-theorem

I'm taking Data Structures and Algorithm course and I'm stuck at this recursive equation:

```
T(n) = logn*T(logn) + n
```

obviously this can't be handled with the use of the Master Theorem, so I was wondering if anybody has any ideas for solving this recursive equation. I'm pretty sure that it should be solved with a change in the parameters, like considering n to be 2^m , but I couldn't manage to find any good fix.

Comment: This is not a recursive equation, for two reasons. First, T(n) depends on T(log n) ,and even if n is an integer log n is in general not. Second, there is no start condition, such as T(0) = 0.

Comment: I dont think these reasons are enough to say that this is not a recursive equation , because after all T(n) depends on another value of T , so this makes it recursive . and according to our instructor the start condition should be guessed by yourself , and sometimes the start condition is not even needed , like when using the master theorem .

Comment: To be precise, functions can be defined **recursively**, equations can have **recurrence**. Did you try enumerating some values for this function? Intelligent guesswork should be the first attempt, it's easy to check if a guess is correct by induction.

Comment: thanks for the correction Daniel , but no guess comes to mind on this one , do you have any in mind ?

Comment: It seems (if I am not wrong), you can atleast calculate the expression for some of the powers of 2. T(1) = 1, T(2) = T(1) + 2, T(4) = 2*T(2) + 4, T(16) = 56, T(256) = 704

Comment: yes , but where would that take us !? :|

Comment: this question was solved at this topic , http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14775/recursive-equation-for-complexity-tn-logn-tlogn-n

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `Theta(n)`.  To prove something is `Theta(n)`, you have to show it is `Omega(n)` and `O(n)`.  `Omega(n)` in this case is obvious because `T(n)>=n`.  To show that `T(n)=O(n)`, first

1. Pick a large finite value `N` such that `log(n)^2 < n/100` for all `n>N`.  This is possible because `log(n)^2=o(n)`.
2. Pick a constant `C>100` such that `T(n)<Cn` for all `n<=N`.  This is possible due to the fact that `N` is finite.

We will show inductively that `T(n)<Cn` for all `n>N`.  Since `log(n)<n`, by the induction hypothesis, we have:

```
T(n) < n + log(n) C log(n) 
     = n + C log(n)^2
     < n + (C/100) n 
     = C * (1/100 + 1/C) * n
     < C/50 * n
     < C*n
```

In fact, for this function it is even possible to show that `T(n) = n + o(n)` using a similar argument.

Comment: dude your final answer is correct , but your proof is faulty ! it is not logn^2 , its logn*T(logn) ! I think you forgot that !

Comment: T(log n) < C log(n) follows from the induction hypothesis.  Are you familiar with proof by induction?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Comment: yes , As I examined my textbook your method was right and I was wrong . I made that mistake because your way of using induction was slightly different than the method I learnt ( like choosing the constants c and n ) . anyway , thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means an official proof but I think it goes like this.

The key is the `+ n` part. Because of this, `T` is bounded below by `o(n)`. (or should that be big omega? I'm rusty.) So let's assume that `T(n) = O(n)` and have a go at that.

Substitute into the original relation

```
T(n) = (log n)O(log n) + n
     = O(log^2(n)) + O(n)
     = O(n)
```

So it still holds.

Comment: this is completely and utterly wrong my friend , I'd vote you down but I cannot .

Comment: hah okay I admit I'm not sure with this solution. Care to elaborate?

Comment: well I think your mistake is that for T(logn) you cannot just write O(logn) , because we do not know what will happen with logn within the function T(logn) .

Comment: @AshkanKzme:  Why is this answer that T(n) is O(n) "completely and utterly wrong" when the solution to the Accepted Answer to your cross-post at cs.SE also says T(n) is O(n)?  There's some abuse of notation in the Answer above, but not much more than what is entailed by the Question itself.

Comment: This is correct.  You could make it a little more rigorous by saying "assume that `T(n)<cn` for `n<5`", and then using strong induction.  (And yes, it should be big omega.)

Comment: Be careful with these kind of proofs (induction proofs) and big-O notation. A simple *assume this-or-that* approach can produce wrong results!